# placing image on table view iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have three rows which are configured programmatically. I want to place an image only on the first row of the table view.  The image has to cover the entire first row(not on the left side of table view cell by default)

Here is my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case 1:

if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
    return 230.0; // first row is 123px high
    }
        default:
            return 100.0; // all other rows are 40px high 
    }
}
-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row) {

            case 0:
            break;      

        case 1:
            if (indexPath.row==1) {

                UIButton *button1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 310, 40)];
                [button1 setTitle:@"Give" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(give)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [button1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
                [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];



                UIButton *button2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 60, 310, 40)];
                [button2 setTitle:@"YouTube" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(Announcements)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [button2.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
                [button2 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];


                UIButton *button3=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                [button3 setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 110, 310, 40)];
                [button3 setTitle:@"Follow us on Twitter" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(Twitter)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [button3.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
                [button3 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:button3];

                UIButton *button4=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                [button4 setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 160, 310, 40)];
                [button4 setTitle:@"Follow us on FaceBook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(Facebook)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [button4.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
                [button4 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [cell.contentView addSubview:button4];

                /*[button1 release];
                [button2 release];
                [button3 release];
                [button4 release];*/

            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a UIImageView to your contentview.

Comment: @saadnib:if i m to use uiimageView i m getting exception..code.NSString *imagefile=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"guitar" ofType:@"jpg"];
     
     UIImageView *li=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imagefile];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:li];

Comment: UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f)];
 [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"guitar.jpg"]];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
 [imgView release];

Comment: @saadnib:thanks man...its working fine but i m getting the image pixels broken...is der any way

Comment: actual your image pixels are broken because the image you have in your project is not as the same size as the frame we are passing in CGRectMake. Look at last two parameters.